# SMF urls to Xenforo urls - Redirect via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, xenforo, smf, smf-forum

I need to redirect old urls of an SMF forum system to new Xenforo.
Old url is :

```
http://www.example.com/forum/index.php?topic=XXXX.0
```

and new url is :

```
http://www.example.com/forum/threads/XXXX/
```

What is the true htaccess code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, though it does assume that your threads have the same ID in both SMF and XF. It should be placed before Xenforo's redirects.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^topic=(\d+).*$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/forum/threads/%1/? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: @motahhari what apache version do you have?

Comment: Apache version 2.4.12

Comment: The same happens to me if you put the lines **after** XF's rewrites. Try putting it just after RewriteEngine On and it should work.

Comment: @motahhari Awesome :) Feel free to accept this answer